# How to use an Alex monadic lexer with Happy?

Tags: haskell, monads, happy, alex

I'm trying to learn using Alex + Happy to build parser, in particular I'm interested in learning to use the `monad` wrapper of Alex. I have already looked at the documentation of Alex and [Happy](http://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-monads.html#sec-lexers) but I they are both, for me, *really* lacking any useful information on using them together. I managed to make them work together with the `basic` and `posn` wrappers, but I'm at a loss with `monad`.

I have already looked at different question on SO about Alex, Happy and monadic lexers (including: [Are there any tutorials on building a simple interpreter using Alex + Happy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113197/are-there-any-tutorials-on-building-a-simple-interpreter-using-alex-happy) but none is able to provide a simple example where `monad` is used.

Most of the code online uses Happy with a custom lexer function, or uses the `basic` or `posn` Alex wrappers.

Here's a simple lexer for an ini-like syntax:

```
{
module IniLexer where
}

%wrapper "monad"



$spaces = [\ \t]
$alpha = [a-zA-Z]
$digits = [0-9]
$alnum = [$alpha$digits]


@identifier = $alpha $alnum*

@comment = \#.*

@integer = $digits+

@boolean = (true) | (false)

@string = \"[^\"]*\"


:-

@integer    { mkL LInteger }
@boolean    { mkL LBoolean }
@string     { mkL LString }

@identifier  { mkL LIdentifier }

\[@identifier\] { mkL LSection }

=           { mkL LAssign }

\;          { mkL LEndAssign }
@comment    ;
[\ \t \n]+  ;


{

data LexemeClass = LInteger | LBoolean | LString | LIdentifier | LSection | LAssign | LEndAssign | LEOF
    deriving (Eq, Show)


mkL :: LexemeClass -> AlexInput -> Int -> Alex Token
mkL c (p, _, _, str) len = let t = take len str
                           in case c of
                                LInteger -> return (IntegerNum ((read t) :: Integer) p)
                                LBoolean -> return (BooleanVal (if t == "true"
                                                                   then True
                                                                   else False
                                                               ) p)
                                LString -> return (StringTxt (take (length t - 2) (drop 1 t)) p)
                                LIdentifier -> return (Identifier t p)
                                LSection -> return (SectionHeader (take (length t - 2) (drop 1 t)) p)
                                LAssign -> return (Assignment p)
                                LEndAssign -> return (EndAssignment p)


-- No idea why I have to write this myself. Documentation doesn't mention it.
alexEOF :: Alex Token
alexEOF = return Eof



data Token = SectionHeader {identifier :: String, position :: AlexPosn} |
             Identifier {name :: String, position :: AlexPosn}          |
             Assignment {position :: AlexPosn}                          |
             EndAssignment {position :: AlexPosn}                       |
             IntegerNum {value :: Integer, position :: AlexPosn}        |
             BooleanVal {istrue :: Bool, position :: AlexPosn}          |
             StringTxt  {text :: String, position :: AlexPosn}          |
             Eof
    deriving (Eq, Show)


}
```

And here's the relative Happy parser:

```
{
module Main where

import IniLexer

}



%name parseIniFile
%error {parseError}
%lexer  {alexMonadScan} {AlexEOF}
%monad {Alex}
%tokentype {Token}
%token
    SECTION     {SectionHeader name _ }
    IDENT       {Identifier name _ }
    '='         {Assignment _ }
    INT         {IntegerNum value _ }
    BOOL        {BooleanVal istrue _ }
    STRING      {StringTxt text _ }
    ';'         {EndAssignment _ }


%%


ConfigFile : SequenceOfSections                    {reverse $1}

SequenceOfSections : {- empty -}                   {   []  }
                   | SequenceOfSections Section    {$2 : $1}


Section : SECTION SectionBody                      {Section (identifier $1) (reverse $2)}


SectionBody : {- empty -}        {[]}
            | SectionBody AssignmentLine ';' {$2 : $1}


AssignmentLine : IDENT '=' Value      {(name $1, $3)}

Value : INT         {IntV (value $1)}
      | BOOL        {BoolV (istrue $1)}
      | STRING      {StringV (text $1)}


{

data Value = IntV Integer | BoolV Bool | StringV String
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Section = Section String [(String, Value)]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data IniFile = IniFile [Section]
    deriving (Eq, Show)


parseError :: [Token] -> Alex a
parseError t = fail "a"

main = do
    s <- getContents
    print $ parseIniFile $ runAlex s alexMonadScan

}
```

Which raises a lot of compiler errors:

```
[...]
Couldn't match expected type `(AlexReturn t1 -> Alex a0) -> t0'
                with actual type `Alex Token'
    The function `alexMonadScan' is applied to one argument,
    but its type `Alex Token' has none
[...]
```

How should I modify the parser to use `alexMonadScan`?
The [Happy](http://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-monads.html#sec-lexers) documentation isn't clear at all and tries hard *not* to use any clarifying example (or the examples provided fail in clarying from my point of view).

If needed I could post my `posn` version of this same lexer+parser.

Comment: Last time I tried this (years ago!), the documentation for the `monad` wrapper was flat-out wrong, and it appears to still be wrong.  I don't recall exactly what I had to do to make it work, but you may be better off generating the wrapper code manually, as e.g. `language-c` and `haskell-src-exts` do.

Comment: The downvoter should explain why he considers this a bad question. I belive I *do* have provided all information required, with a MWE and everything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your lexer's definition is completely fine as far as I can tell. Assuming there are no bugs there, the only problems you need to fix are in your parser's configuration. The first thing is that the lexer you are using is the wrong one. While that function is the interface to the Alex lexer, it has the type

```
alexMonadScan :: Alex result
```

But the lexer Happy wants is of type

```
lexer :: (Token -> P a) -> P a
```

Where `P` is the monad we are using. What this is saying is that the lexer should provide us an `Alex a` when given a continuation. A simple wrapper is what we need here:

```
lexwrap :: (Token -> Alex a) -> Alex a
lexwrap cont = do
    token <- alexMonadScan
    cont token
```

or equivalently

```
lexwrap = (alexMonadScan >>=)
```

Second, using `alexEOF` in the `%lexer` directive will cause your parser to fail on every input. The name you supply there is inserted in to a branch of a case statement in generated code, so you must use the name of a data constructor rather than a value --- in particular, you need to use the data constructor that Alex will emit to signal EOF.

This makes our lexer line in the parser a little different.

```
%lexer {lexwrap} {Eof}
```

(As a side note, *this* is the reason that you need to write `alexEOF = return Eof` yourself. The data constructor you return inside `alexEOF` needs to pattern-match against the data constructor you identify to Happy as the one that ends the file. Alex has no way of knowing what you want to emit, and Happy has no way of knowing what you chose to emit via Alex.)

Now the next problem is that your parseError's type is incorrect. When using just a monad, that is indeed the type you need, but when you add a lexer into the mix, your parseError must have a different type. Also, using fail is probably not advised, so here is a slightly better definition:

```
parseError :: Token -> Alex a
parseError _ = alexError "Why is using happy and alex so hard"
```

Finally, the main function is definied a little strange here. what we want to do to call the parser is to invoke it with runAlex. So here is a quick wrapper for it. The string passed in is the string that you wish to parse.

```
parse :: String -> Either String [Section]
parse s = runAlex s parseIniFile
```

The type of the function parse is determined by the parseIniFile's definition. Here, it is an `Alex [Section]` so an `Either String [Section]` is returned.

I think that's everything.

Comment: Sorry, I'll fix that. I got it working after working with it for a bit.

Comment: Do you know how could one use the token error in Happy for reporting it a parsing error and continue on with the parsing, to show all possible parsing errors in the file?

Comment: I honestly do not. However, [http://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-monads.html] has a description of using the error token. It seems to me to be a very limited form of recovery since you have to assign it to only one of the non-terminals in order to avoid a conflict. One thing that you could do is to handle the errors yourself by using extra tokens in your result type.

Comment: The generated parser uses the EOF token in the `%lexer` directive as the first pattern in a case on the token passed to the continuation.  With `alexEOF`, the pattern is a variable that matches anything, so every token appears to be EOF.  Instead, it should be set to the pattern that matches the EOF token returned by the custom `alexEOF` function.

Comment: The advice "However, I think to be safe you should use alexEOF instead." is **EXTREMELY MISLEADING** and it causes a **SILENT ERROR IN THE COMPILED CODE** that will make the parser fail **EVERY TIME**. Following the advice in this question will make your parser fail **EVERY TIME, ON ANY INPUT**. For more info, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996489), which led me to uncover the error.

Comment: In fact, @pat pointed it out almost a year ago, but I missed it as I skimmed through the comments. I have edited the answer to correct the error, since this question pops up near the top of many Google searches relating to Alex and Happy. (Honestly, I'm shocked that it stood unfixed for so long, but I'm just frustrated that spent so long tracking it down.)

Comment: Great answer. Got my Happy monadic parser and Alex monadic lexer working in no time.