# What causes Happy to throw a parse error?

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy, alex

I've written a lexer in Alex and I'm trying to hook it up to a parser written in Happy. I'll try my best to summarize my problem without pasting huge chunks of code.

I know from my unit tests of my lexer that the string `"\x7"` is lexed to:

```
[TokenNonPrint '\x7', TokenEOF]
```

My token type (spit out by the lexer), is `Token`. I've defined `lexWrap` and `alexEOF` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315739/how-to-use-an-alex-monadic-lexer-with-happy), which gives me the following header and token declarations:

```
%name parseTokens 
%tokentype { Token }
%lexer { lexWrap } { alexEOF }
%monad { Alex }
%error { parseError }

%token
  NONPRINT {TokenNonPrint $$}
  PLAIN { TokenPlain $$ }
```

I invoke the parser+lexer combo with the following:

```
parseExpr :: String -> Either String [Expr]
parseExpr s = runAlex s parseTokens
```

And here are my first few productions:

```
exprs :: { [Expr] }
exprs
  : {- empty -} { trace "exprs 30" [] }
  | exprs expr { trace "exprs 31" $ $2 : $1 }

nonprint :: { Cmd }
  : NONPRINT { NonPrint $ parseNonPrint $1}

expr :: { Expr }
expr
  : nonprint {trace "expr 44" $ Cmd $ $1}
  | PLAIN { trace "expr 37" $ Plain $1 }
```

I'll leave out the datatype declarations of `Expr` and `NonPrint` since they're long and only the constructors `Cmd` and `NonPrint` matter here. The function `parseNonPrint` is defined at the bottom of Parse.y as:

```
parseNonPrint :: Char -> NonPrint
parseNonPrint '\x7' = Bell
```

Also, my error handling function looks like:

```
parseError :: Token -> Alex a
parseError tokens = error ("Error processing token: " ++ show tokens)
```

Written like this, I expect the following hspec test to pass:

```
parseExpr "\x7" `shouldBe` Right [Cmd (NonPrint Bell)]
```

But instead, I see `"exprs 30"` print *once* (even though I'm running 5 different unit tests) and all of my tests of `parseExpr` return `Right []`. I don't understand why that would be the case, but I changed the `exprs` production to prevent it:

```
exprs :: { [Expr] }
exprs
  : expr { trace "exprs 30" [$1] }
  | exprs expr { trace "exprs 31" $ $2 : $1 }
```

Now all of my tests fail on the first token they hit --- `parseExpr "\x7"` fails with:

```
uncaught exception: ErrorCall (Error processing token: TokenNonPrint '\a')
```

And I'm thoroughly confused, since I would expect the parser to take the path `exprs -> expr -> nonprint -> NONPRINT` and succeed. I don't see why this input would put the parser in an error state. None of the `trace` statements are hit (optimized away?).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you point us to the code - i.e. a github repo?

Comment: @user5402 https://github.com/pscollins/ansi-parser has all of the code. It is a little sloppy at the moment, especially the labeling of tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the cause of this error was the innocuous line

```
%lexer { lexWrap } { alexEOF }
```

which was recommended by the linked question about using Alex with Happy (unfortunately, one of the top Google results for queries like "using Alex as a monadic lexer with Happy). The fix is to change it to the following:

```
%lexer { lexWrap } { TokenEOF }
```

I had to dig in to the generated code to uncover the issue. It is caused by the code derived from the `%tokens` directive, which looks as follows (I commented out all of my token declarations except for `TokenNonPrint` while trying to track down the error):

```
happyNewToken action sts stk
    = lexWrap(\tk -> 
    let cont i = happyDoAction i tk action sts stk in
    case tk of {
    alexEOF -> happyDoAction 2# tk action sts stk; -- !!!!
    TokenNonPrint happy_dollar_dollar -> cont 1#;
    _ -> happyError' tk
    })
```

Evidently, Happy transforms each line of the `%tokens` directive in to one branch of a pattern match. It *also* inserts a branch for whatever was identified to it as the EOF token in the `%lexer` directive.

By inserting the name of a value, `alexEOF`, rather than a data constructor, `TokenEOF`, this branch of the case statement has the effect of re-binding the name `alexEOF` to whatever token was passed in to `lexWrap`, shadowing the original binding and short-circuiting the case statement so that it hits the EOF rule every time, which somehow results in Happy entering an error state.

The mistake isn't caught by the type system, since the identifier `alexEOF` (or `TokenEOF`) doesn't appear anywhere else in the generated code. Misusing the `%lexer` directive like this will cause GHC to emit a warning, but, since the warning appears in generated code, it's impossible to distinguish it from all of the other harmless warnings the code throws out.